# TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, prestashop

I am having troubles adding this carousel to my prestashop template.

It returns me the following error:

TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
navigation : true

And the code using to initialize it is this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true
  });
});
```

I am trying to solve it, but seems imposible, since on an empty html page it works but not when I use it on the Prestashop.

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `owl.carousel.min.js` file in your home page  and before the file in which you are using add the following code:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true
  });
```

Then only it will work.

Answer (score 14):

You will get this error if the jquery file is loading after the owl carousel file.

(Make sure your reference to jquery is above the owl carousel reference js file)

Comment: Thanks for starting this answer. Try offering insight on where they might look for the problem and how they might fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

The reason sometime html executed inline script before external script loaded perfectly.
I get solution by this way .
I just added **defer** attribute to my **`owl.carousel source`** calling like ..

**`<script defer src="plugins/OwlCarousel2.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`**

Documentation about defer attribute --> [att_script_defer-link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

Comment: This fixed my issue. I tried all methods of ordering jquery and js files, cdn links of owl carousel.

Answer (score 7):

If JavaScript files loading is affected by some latency, you can check if function is defined before call it.

**Check with [jQuery.isFunction](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/)**

```
if($.isFunction('owlCarousel')){
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true
  });
}
```

**Check with [JavaScript typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**

```
if(typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use {literal} {/literal} tags. It's usually reccomanded to put javascript inside those tags in .tpl files (smarty) . Javascript might work without the tags but can sometimes return a error ( like in your case )

BR's

Comment: I also tried this but keeps without work. It just keeps me returning me the same error.

Comment: how are you pulling the js in to the file ? Are you using pretsatshop determined pathways in .php (whatever core/module file is displaying ur .tpl file) file ?

Example is here:

       $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'views/js/YOUR.js');

Comment: I am just adding the script between <script> tags on header.tpl

Comment: Are you going to use that script on every single page ? And even then you should still add it like that ( if you are using it in within a module , for example ) In your case prestashop will load the script every single time even when it's not being used.

Comment: I just want to use it in the home page (otherwise, thanks for warning me about it will be displayed on every single page). So i will have to add the script on the prestashop .php path and add the script? And what about the begining of the function? On the php file also? Or I'll have to make another JS file with the function?

Comment: Only reason I can think of is that your link to the javascript is not correct as the function can't execute. 

To display something ONLY on homepage without some module or core files edit use this : 

{if $page_name == 'index'}
            
{/if}

Comment: Hey user2831723, i will give a try later. Otherwise I am asking the same question on prestashop forums, and with the help of moderators, we checked the code and the path is correct

Comment: I'll try to do some testing when I get some time. I'll get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I got fixed by checking if the selector exist or not. As this was the issue on my website I had added code in footer for a single page but it was throwing error or other pages where that selector don't exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var owl = $('.servicesCarosal');
            
    //console.log(owl);

    if (owl.length) { 
        owl.owlCarousel({

        });
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add `Owl Carousel Css` and `Owl Carousel Theme Default Css` files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" integrity="sha512-UTNP5BXLIptsaj5WdKFrkFov94lDx+eBvbKyoe1YAfjeRPC+gT5kyZ10kOHCfNZqEui1sxmqvodNUx3KbuYI/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" integrity="sha512-OTcub78R3msOCtY3Tc6FzeDJ8N9qvQn1Ph49ou13xgA9VsH9+LRxoFU6EqLhW4+PKRfU+/HReXmSZXHEkpYoOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Then add `Jquery` and `Owl Carousel Js` files.

***Make sure to put `Jquery` before `Owl Carousel Js`.***

Like this:

```
<!-- put jquery before owl carousel -->
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- owl carousel -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **jquery.min.js** and **owl.carousel.min.js** files in your home page and add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  if(owl.length){
    owl.owlCarousel({
      navigation : true
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These might be helpful.
Follow the steps

1. Import/link the owlCarousel.js file
2. Link owlCarousel.js file after jQuery.js file.
3. Hard reload: ctrl + shift + R

Still facing problem?

It might be for this reason:

Your `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()` function is executing before the loading of JS files (owlCarousel.js,jQuery.js)

Most of the case you can solve this issue by using this tricks & increasing timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()
    },
    2000);
});
```

Comment: I'm running Rails... so it's pretty hard to get the order of scripts to load right. THIS is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just add the js file right above your function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!--DO NOT ENTER ANY EXTERNAL LINK IN BETWEEN-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would that help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I am using Webpack to bundle my assets, I needed to follow [this section](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2#webpack) on the owl's page on GitHub.

The section states that you should add JQuery like so:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

//...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
],
//...
```

**index.js**

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Your **Jquery** file and **owl.js** file to header section

Answer (score -1):

For me, adding `item`class to carousel-item

-result is below-

`<div class="item carousel-item" style="margin: auto;">`

solved problem.