# Error in JS plugin (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I try to use https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Plugin

But I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>       at owl.carousel.min.js:479
>       at owl.carousel.min.js:494

In this code

```
a.fn.owlCarousel = function (b) {
        var c = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.each(function () {
            var d = a(this),
                f = d.data("owl.carousel");
            f || (f = new e(this, "object" == typeof b && b), d.data("owl.carousel", f), a.each(["next", "prev", "to", "destroy", "refresh", "replace", "add", "remove"], function (b, c) {
                f.register({
                    type: e.Type.Event,
                    name: c
                }), f.$element.on(c + ".owl.carousel.core", a.proxy(function (a) {
                    a.namespace && a.relatedTarget !== this && (this.suppress([c]), f[c].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)), this.release([c]))
                }, f))
            })), "string" == typeof b && "_" !== b.charAt(0) && f[b].apply(f, c)
        })
    }
```

Here is how I use plugin in my code

```
 <script>
    $('#display').click(function () {
        var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
        var model = {
            vacancyId: vacancyId
    };

        $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Links", "Questions")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var question2 = data;
        for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length - 1; i++) {
            var videoHTML = '<video width="320" height="240" style="margin-left: 130px;margin-top: 20px;" controls>';
            videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
            videoHTML += '</video>';
            $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);
            $(".videolist").owlCarousel();
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: This is much related to script loading order. Have the page loaded Carousel plugin before jQuery? If no, probably `$` variable already assigned with other than jQuery and requires IIFE such like `(function ( $ ) { ... }( jQuery ));` or `jQuery.noConflict(true);` to restore it.

Comment: So where I need to write `( jQuery ));` in plugin code?@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: jQuery is included@RobWilkins

Comment: I dont understand how to do this correctly @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: From the Carousel script, `a.fn.owlCarousel` stands for `$.fn.owlCarousel`, which certainly requires jQuery which uses `$` variable. Try changing script loading order which jQuery must be in topmost part, if it still persists add IIFE mentioned above inside HTML script tag (leave plugin contents as is).

Comment: Is the video loaded blank, generating invalid markup or something else? Edit the question which provides further details related to video embedding since script loading order problem had already resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141947/discussion-between-eugene-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that script loading order went wrong or out of order:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at
>   owl.carousel.min.js:479 at owl.carousel.min.js:494

Since `Owl.Carousel` plugin requires jQuery to run, place `jQuery` on topmost of all scripts order then place `owl.carousel.min.js` afterwards like this example (read [Owl Carousel plugin docs](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html) for further info):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Second, ensure the Carousel plugin loaded inside `$(document).ready` scope, to initialize all DOM-related objects:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#display').click(function () {
            // other stuff
        });

        $.ajax({
                // other stuff

                success: function (data) {
                    var question2 = data;
                    for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length - 1; i++) {

                        // other stuff

                        $(".videolist").owlCarousel();
                    }
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The last important thing to remember with: not all scripts can be loaded simultaneously (which may breaking script order at certain point affected by latency), therefore you need to check existence of [`owlCarousel`](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js) before invocation with either [`isFunction`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/):

```
if ($.isFunction('owlCarousel')) {
    $(".videolist").owlCarousel();
}
```

or using simple `typeof` operator (credits to *@Nolwennig*):

```
if(typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
    $(".videolist").owlCarousel();
}
```

Related issues:

[jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807430/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined-anonymous-fun)

[TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661292/typeerror-owlcarousel-is-not-a-function)