# Google analytics integration for orders without online payment transaction in Woocommerce 3

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics

I'm trying to add information about orders in the Google analytics. But the statistics do not show the receipt of information about orders. The site does not use online payments (perhaps the reason is related to this). I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174961/google-analytics-integration-for-a-custom-order-received-page-in-woocommerce-3/52190053?noredirect=1#_=_)

I added code to functions.php in my theme directory.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'google_analytics_integration', 20 );
function google_analytics_integration(){
    ?>
    <script>
        ga('require', 'ecommerce');
        <?php

        // GET the WC_Order object instance from, the Order ID
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $order_key = $order->get_order_key();

        $transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id(); // Doesn't always exist

        $transaction_id = $order_id; // (Or the order key or the transaction ID if it exist)

        ?>
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id':          '<?php echo $transaction_id; // To be checked ?>',
            'affiliation': '<?php echo 'UA-130000602-1'; // replace by yours ?>',
            'revenue':     '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>',
            'shipping':    '<?php echo $order->get_shipping_total(); ?>',
            'tax':         '<?php echo $order->get_total_tax(); ?>',
            'currency':    '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); // Optional ?>'
        }); <?php

        // LOOP START: Iterate through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) :
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Get the product categories for the product
        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $category = reset($categories); // Keep only the first product category
        ?>
        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
            'id':       '<?php echo $transaction_id; ?>',
            'name':     '<?php echo $item->get_name(); ?>',
            'sku':      '<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>',
            'category': '<?php echo $category; ?>',
            'price':    '<?php echo wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);  // OR wc_get_price_including_tax($product) ?>',
            'quantity': '<?php echo $item->get_quantity(); ?>',
            'currency': '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); // Optional ?>'
        });
        <?php
        endforeach; // LOOP END
        ?>
        ga('ecommerce:send');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I added the counter code to header.php

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-130000602-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-130000602-1');
</script>
```

My account Google analytics settings:
[image: Google analytics settings]

Identified conflicts in the script. Footer disappears.
[image: Identified conflicts]
[image: Identified conflicts]

Answer (score 2):

First check with the dummy data is its working fine or not.

```
  add_action('wp_head','add_gscript_trans');

        function add_gscript_trans(){?>

        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-130000602-1', 'auto');
        /* To load the ecommerce plugin, use the following command: */
        ga('require', 'ecommerce');
    /* You add transaction data to the shopping cart using the ecommerce:addTransaction command:*/

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
      'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
      'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
      'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
    });

    /* Next, to add items to the shopping cart, you use the ecommerce:addItem command: */

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
      'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
      'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
      'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
      'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
    });
   /* Finally, once you have configured all your ecommerce data in the shopping cart, you send the data to Google Analytics using the ecommerce:send command: */

   ga('ecommerce:send');

    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
    <?php }
```

For more details see this link : [E-commerce Track](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)

Comment: Thank you! This is valid for understandable reasons. The question is how to correctly break the code into the counter and the code on the "thank you" page.

Comment: have you check by disable owl carousel plugins or by comment the owl code. i hope it will help you to track the error. Thanks

Comment: The reason unfortunately is not in this owl script. In my code that removes the footer. In the footer, the carousel script is connected. Therefore, an error occurs.

Comment: Ok, I can understand what you are saying, but did you checked your code by removing owl carousel i just means for debug by removing owl may be it help you to debug your code. Because if any js error will throws then any js script will be unable to run.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the footer disappeared anyway. There was no mistake with the owl since it was turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this page will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111464/7118098

Also, can't see the previous line where `owl` is defined, but it looks like it's defined from a jQuery `$()` from an element ID.  Perhaps check that it exists and that owlCarousel isn't deferred and is indeed attached to the element you're referencing before .owlCarousel() is called on it.

Comment: Thanks! I checked. Error with the carousel does not matter. This is a consequence of the fact that my code above breaks the footer. So the script owl does not load. That is, I have the wrong counter code and google analytics integration i think.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [WooCommerce Google Analytics Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-google-analytics-integration/) By WooCommerce or [DuracellTomi's Google Tag Manager for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/) By Thomas Geiger