# Laravel Carousel Owl

Tags: javascript, laravel

I need to use Carousel Owl in my Laravel project.
My JS:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';

const carouselEl = document.querySelector('.owl-carousel');
var $ = require('jquery');

$(document).ready(function() {
    carouselEl.owlCarousel();
});
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.webpackConfig((webpack) => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            }),
        ],
    };
});
```

When I compiled this, there was error:

```
carouselEl.owlCarousel is not a function.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28390573/4575350

Comment: can u put your blade.php so can check how u are include `app.js`

Comment: Webpack.mix.js:
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .js('resources/js/script.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Blade: <script async src="{{ mix('js/script.js') }}"></script> 

Everything in this script works, I have issue just with carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```js
const carouselEl = document.querySelector('.owl-carousel');

$(document).ready(function() {
    carouselEl.owlCarousel();
});
```

with

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

your code is not working becouse `carouselEl` it is just a html element instance so u can call `owlCarousel()` to that